# How to keep my stack alive

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, redis

I'm an experienced dev, but new to the sysadmin side of things. I'm running a node.js application, that uses a redis database and has nginx running a reverse proxy to server the node pages over https.

My concern is that one or all 3 will fall over under heavy load or error and there's nothing to get it started back up. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

My server is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Many thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the easiest setup and ongoing monitoring for a new sysadmin came from Monit (http://mmonit.com/monit/)

Answer (score 1):

One of the best option is to use upstart.
The original documentation is pretty complicated, but take a look:
http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/

And here is what you exactly need, if I correctly understand your issue:
http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2012/02/14/upstart-scripts-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

There is a new solution for that called [pm2](http://github.com/Unitech/pm2). I use it and it's working fine.